# How to go look back 7 days in a hive query

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql, where-clause

I've got a sql where I need to constantly look back 4 days. This code would run once a week so I need to look 7 days back. My where clause is set stationary and looks between two dates, However I need it to look back 7 days all the time.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
WITH gps_traces AS(
    SELECT 
    gtrips.trip_id
    , to_date(gtrips.trip_date) as trip_date
    , gtrips.fleet_id
    , vin.vehicle_vin
    , gtrips.driver_id
    , gtrips.trip_distance_travelled
    , gtrips.trip_duration
    , to_timestamp(gdata.trip_timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") as gps_timestamp
    , rank() over 
        (partition by gtrips.trip_id 
            order by to_timestamp(gdata.trip_timestamp, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss") asc) 
        as timestamp_rank
    , gdata.latitude
    , gdata.longitude
    , gdata.postcode
    FROM 
        cms.gps_trips gtrips
    INNER JOIN
        cms.gps_data gdata
        ON gtrips.trip_id = gdata.trip_id
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                DISTINCT --why are there duplicates?
                    devices.vehicle_id
                    , devices.vehicle_vin
                    , devices.data_effective_timestamp
            FROM
                cms.devices devices
            INNER JOIN
                 (
                    SELECT
                        vehicle_id
                        , max(data_effective_timestamp) as data_effective_timestamp
                    FROM
                        cms.devices
                    GROUP BY
                        vehicle_id
                ) max_data_effective
                ON devices.vehicle_id = max_data_effective.vehicle_id
                AND devices.data_effective_timestamp = max_data_effective.data_effective_timestamp
        ) vin
    WHERE 
        to_date(gtrips.trip_date) >= "2020-12-11" --Only keeping this date for now
    AND
        to_date(gtrips.trip_date) <= "2020-12-17"
    AND 
        gtrips.fleet_id = 10211 --Only keeping due for this example
    )

    SELECT 
        gps.trip_id
        , gps.trip_date
        , gps.fleet_id
        , gps.vehicle_vin
        , gps.driver_id
        , gps.trip_distance_travelled
        , gps.trip_duration
        , gps.gps_timestamp
        , gps.latitude
        , gps.longitude
        , gps.postcode
        , gps1.gps_timestamp as next_timestamp
        , gps1.latitude as next_latitude
        , gps1.longitude as next_longitude
            , ACOS(
                SIN(RADIANS(gps.latitude))*SIN(RADIANS(gps1.latitude)) + 
                COS(RADIANS(gps.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(gps1.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(gps1.longitude) - RADIANS(gps.longitude))
            )*3958.76 AS COSINES_DISTANCE
            , ASIN(
                SQRT(
                    POWER(SIN((RADIANS(gps.latitude) - RADIANS(gps1.latitude))/2), 2) +
                    COS(RADIANS(gps.latitude))*COS(RADIANS(gps1.latitude))*
                    POWER(SIN((RADIANS(gps.longitude) - RADIANS(gps1.longitude))/2), 2)
                )
            )*3958.76*2 AS HAVERSINE_DISTANCE 
            , (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(gps1.gps_timestamp) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(gps.gps_timestamp)) AS GPS_INTERVAL
        FROM
            gps_traces gps
        LEFT JOIN
            gps_traces gps1
                ON gps.trip_id = gps1.trip_id
                AND gps.timestamp_rank = (gps1.timestamp_rank - 1)
        ORDER BY
            gps.fleet_id
            , gps.trip_id
            , gps.timestamp_rank
```

specifically, I'm needing to change this snippet here:

```
WHERE 
        to_date(gtrips.trip_date) >= "2020-12-11" --Needs to be rolling 7 days
    AND
        to_date(gtrips.trip_date) <= "2020-12-17"
```

I tried converting the date but it's falling over in Hive. Can someone assist with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use current_date:

```
WHERE 
        to_date(gtrips.trip_date) >= date_sub(current_date, 7) --7 days back
    AND
        to_date(gtrips.trip_date) <= current_date
```

Or pass current date as a -hiveconf parameter:

```
WHERE 
        to_date(gtrips.trip_date) >= date_sub(to_date('${hiveconf:current_date}'), 7) --7 days back
    AND
        to_date(gtrips.trip_date) <= to_date('${hiveconf:current_date}')
```